# AngularJS ng-message directive always showing message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I am trying to set the select field in the view to be required. So I'm having the below tags in my view.html

```
<form name="homeForm">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
    <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">Laboratory Name</label>
        <select name="labName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.labName" required>
            <option ng-repeat="lab in labList" value="{{lab.id}}">{{lab.value}}</option>
        </select>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.labName.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.requestTypeName.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was hoping the `This field is required` will show up only when there is no data selected. But irrespective of the field has data or not  `This field is required` shows up like below
[image]

Is there something I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-messages` directive is in a separate library module and must be included as a dependency.

## Example

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app",["ngMessages"])
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ngMessages Module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages).

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the same input name in your input and in your ng-message. Doing this, you don't even need to have ng-if. For example:

```
<form name="form">
  <input name="fullname" type="text" ng-model="fullname" required/>
  <div ng-messages="form.$submitted && form.fullname.$error">
    <p ng-message="required" class="help-block">This field is required</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

In this case I am using form.$submitted. You can remove that, replace it with touched/dirty or whatever. The principle is the same.

Comment: I am doing the same in my other application and it works there and not sure this could be if I am missing an angular directive/library

Comment: well, you need to add ng-messages directive for this to work. Anyway, you dont need that ng-if nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

You are using `homeForm.requestTypeName` in the `ng-if`, and there is no input control named `requestTypeName`, i guess you must use `homeForm.labName` as you use in the `ng-message` attribute.

Basically, change the `ng-if` to `ng-if="homeForm.labName.$touched"`

TL;DR;

You could use as well the `homeForm.labName.$error.required` for checking if actually the end user has passed away that field without entering some input.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I have `homeForm.labName.$touched` still behaves the same

Comment: `homeForm.labName.$error` is not working either it is always showing up the error message

Comment: try to put somewhere in the html something like `<pre>{{homeForm | json}}</pre>` it really helps what is actually inside homeForm object.  JUST be sure to put that html (`<pre>`) element as a child of the form tag.

Comment: I am not sure If I am missing any directive/lib, the calendar also look screwed up. Do you think anything I should install through Nuget

Comment: @trx you will have to excuse as i have no more clues... angular installation is quite straightforward.. but perils of configuration are always present. Take previous tip of using a pre tag for displaying the form object on the screen using the `json` angular filter , and start working with that (you will see how it will change dinamically)... really wish you good luck on this!